# Create a sum during insert into

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have:

```
create table myT(
    p1  float(6,2),
    p2  float(6,2),
    p3  float(6,2),
    date timestamp not null DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    primary key(date)
);
```

and this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER sum BEFORE INSERT ON myT FOR EACH ROW SET @p3= @p2+@p1;
```

doing this insert into:

```
INSERT INTO `myT`(`p1`,`p2`) VALUES (10, 2);
```

I got a null value in p3, while i expect 12

Comment: Did your create trigger statement succeed? Since `sum` is a reserved word, I can imagine that that statement did not execute propertly.

Comment: I tried with another name, but it gives me a null

Comment: @GolezTrol . . . The statement executes properly (I think) but only affects the value of variables.  The initial trigger example in the MySQL documentation could be confusing if you don't read it in detail:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the trigger you want:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER sum BEFORE INSERT ON myT
FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.p3 = NEW.p2 + NEW.p1;

DELIMITER ;
```

There seems to be no need to user variables in this trigger.